# Getting amount of free memory and total available memory

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, virtual-machine, dalvik

I have an application which is performing some memory intensive tasks. I am trying to figure out what the total available memory is and what the available free memory is. I am doing so by using `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` and `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()`

I am curious if the result I am getting is the total amount of free memory and total memory on the device or if it is the total amount of memory available to that instance of the Dalvik VM that the application is running on top of? I would appreciate some feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the JavaDocs, those should be in terms of the heap for your process. That being said:

- [`getMemoryClass()` on `ActivityManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29) is a more Android-y way to determine the heap size for your process.
- Because Dalvik's garbage collector is non-compacting, memory reported by methods like `freeMemory()` will overstate how much you can allocate. By "non-compacting", I mean that if you free up two blocks of memory that happen to be adjacent, the garbage collector leaves them as two blocks of memory. Contrast this to the Java VM, which will recognize that the two blocks are adjacent and update the heap to reflect one larger free block rather than two smaller free blocks. The non-compacting garbage collector means that your heap is more prone to fragmentation than complete exhaustion. You will try to allocate some large block and get an `OutOfMemoryError`, not because the heap lacks free memory, but because there is no single free block big enough for your request.

Comment: "if you free up two blocks of memory that happen to be adjacent, the garbage collector leaves them as two blocks of memory." That is incorrect. If blocks are truly adjacent, they'll get coalesced. Dalvik's GC doesn't compact or copy, and what that means is: Chunks of memory that are in use will not get moved to new locations.

Comment: @danfuzz: Thanks for the clarification! The overall point still stands, though, in that heap fragmentation (no single large-enough block) is still a significant issue, precluding any simple means of measuring "free memory" in a useful fashion.

Comment: Indeed. I didn't intend to argue with that.